# Pandas - chunks from multiple files to list/collection to process them with multiprocessing as one collection of chunks from many files

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, chunks

I've been reading stackoverflow for a long time, usually I was able to find the answer or solve the problem by my own. Today it's time for my first question.

***1. The Setup.***

- Python 3.10.4
- Pandas 1.4.2

***2. The Plan.***

I need to do some ETL on 3 large CSV files (~900k rows each). I just finished the script but it's a bit slow. I can't do to much with IO but I can force my script to run on all avaialable CPUs so **multiprocessing** became my choice. I easily manage to **read_csv** in parallel as a test, unfortunatelly my script is very memory hungry, I quickly **run out of RAM**. I've expected this. My next step was to **chunk** the files, collect all chunks from all files in some container and put them to the **Pool**. Let workers iterate over all the chunks and do the job efficeintly. Nope!

***3. The Problem.***

I don't know how to append/merge/combine/gather **'TextFileReader'** objects (chunks from read_csv()). **Is it possible to create collection of chunks from multiple files like a queue?**

***4. My solution for now.***

At the moment I worked around this by appending large CSVs into one large file, automatically I receive entire collection of chunks as I'm chunking only one file. I found this solution as an inconvenient and not elegant as I need to produce additional file 2,5 GB file and it also takes some time.

***5. Dreamed solution.***

Multiple CSVs => chunked => combined collection of their chunks

***6. My mediocre attempts.***

```
def csv2chunks(file_list):
    chunks = []
    for file in file_list:
        chunks.append(pd.read_csv(filename, dtype='string[pyarrow]', usecols=['Year', 'Month', 'Term'], chunksize=10000, iterator=True))
    return chunks
    
def main():
    files = os.path.join("./", "volume PN FY*.csv")
    files = glob.glob(files) 
    file_list = files

    with Pool(processes=3) as pool: # or whatever your hardware can support
        df_list = pool.map(csv2chunks), file_list)
        combined_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
    
    return combined_df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = main()
```

I have a feeling that I missed something, I can't figure that out. I did not include ETL script as it's just data manipulation which is irrelevant here.

I will appreciate any advice/help or knowledge to better understand nature of 'TextFileReader' object and how to manipulate this creature. If something is unclear, require some more details please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the data manipulation happens inside `csv2chunks`? Is this what you are trying to do: pass each csv to separate process, process reads and changes data inside csv, process returns the edited data, parent compiles the data into one giant dataframe?

Comment: Generally yes, The plan was to create a function which will execute ETL script on each chunk, everythin will be distributed to workers. I would like to avoid processing 3 files at once, i thought about processing chunks in queue doesn't matter where they come from. The output is one dataframe saved as Parquet.

Comment: I think storing the dataframe in shared memory would make much more sense here. The processes can then edit the dataframe itself and concatenating would be much simpler as well. This offcourse assumes that the csv are small enough that you can load *atleast* one instance of each in memory (since they would be in shared memory it **won't** have to be duplicated and stored again for each process you create). I don't think this would be a problem, since you are planning to load a combined dataframe later anyway. I don't know much about the `TextFileReader` class so I can't help you there though.